# Finding machines with a character match in a certain string position

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, match

I'm working on a query where I want to only return computer names where the 7th character is "K"

```
select distinct s.Name0 as 'Computer Name', 
s.User_Name0 as 'Last Logon user', 
os.Caption0 as 'Operating System',
u.Full_User_Name0 as 'Full User Name',
s.AD_Site_Name0 as 'Site'


from v_R_System s
full outer join v_R_User u on u.User_Name0 like s.User_Name0
full outer join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM os on os.ResourceID = s.ResourceID
where os.Caption0 like '%Enterprise%'
and os.Caption0 not like '%server%'
```

I'm trying to return all workstations running enterprise that have a "K" as the 7th character in addition to my other two where statements.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's SQL server 2012 and I'm using SQL Server management studio

Comment: It's good practice to use square brackets around names with spaces. Using names with spaces is not a good idea.

Comment: Good tip, thank you, I'll do that in the future.  I tried the charindex solution recommended below but it's pulling only 35 or so machines when I know there are significantly more machines running Windows Enterprise and with "K" as the 7th character.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The full answer depends on your SQL dialect, but you'll probably want to use something like T-SQL's CHARINDEX function in your where clause:

```
where os.Caption0 like '%Enterprise%'
and os.Caption0 not like '%server%'
AND CHARINDEX('K', s.Name0) = 7
```

[This is a great article that details your other string-manipulation options in T-SQL](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx#CHARINDEX), some of which apply to other dialects.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason the query is only returning 35 or so machines.  I know there are significantly more machines than this running windows enterprise with 'K' as the 7th character. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the other parts of your WHERE clause. You may find that the os.Caption0 field isn't populated in a way that's consistent with your assumptions; removing those filters will let you look at the data and figure out how to adjust your query.